# grunt-bower-install won't include my css files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, bower

I'm quite new to bower and grunt, so basic things work bad for me.

I've `bower install --save bootstrap` and want `grunt-bower-install` to update my js & css files, according to [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-install)

It works great with the .js files, and I have successfully updated my `index.html`

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

But my dist/application.css haven't changed (just empty file)

My `Gruntfile.coffee`:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    coffee:
      compile:
        files:
          'dist/application.js': 'app/assets/javascripts/*.coffee'
    bowerInstall:
      target:
        src: [
          'index.html'
          'dist/application.css'
        ]

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-bower-install'
```

What should I do to my application.css automatically require bootstrap's `.css` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!

Just place this in `head` tag

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

And run `grunt bowerInstall` again

Comment: I did it and it is not working. Did you change anything to your config ?

Comment: No. I haven't change anything

Comment: It was a bug with the latest version of bootstrap, downgrading it to 3.2 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change bower.json file located in bower_modules/bootstrap/

Add at the end another propery:

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
        "main": [
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ]
    }
}
```

Override tells bowerInstall plugin to look for file in dist/css/bootstrap/css in order to create link path in html file.

Second option is to downgrade bootstrap version to 3.3.4 by specifying version of bootstrap in bower.json file.